# AngularJS populate select using scope variable

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, binding, angularjs-scope, html-select

Trying to get a simple binding going with a html select and a scope variable but the select is not populating with the right value.

```
<select ng-model="noOfReps" name="reps" id="reps">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
          </select>
```

This is what I have in my controller

```
$scope.noOfReps = 2;
```

But the result is a dropdown which has all the values 1 through 6 but nothing is selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

model value should be a string in order to match with the option value:

> If you are setting the option value with the option's value attribute, or textContent, the value will always be a string which means that the model value must also be a string

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select